# django send contact form to email raise error

Tags: python, django, email, contact-form

I want to send a contact form to my gmail.

views.py:

```
def contact(request):
errors = []
if request.method == 'POST':
    if not request.POST.get('subject', ''):
        errors.append('Enter a subject.')
    if not request.POST.get('message', ''):
        errors.append('Enter a message.')
    if request.POST.get('email') and '@' not in request.POST['email']:
        errors.append('Enter a valid e-mail address.')
    if not errors:
        send_mail(
            request.POST['subject'],
            request.POST['message'],
            request.POST.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
            ['mypersonalemail@gmail.com'],
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/contact/thanks/')
return render(request, 'contact_form.html',
    {'errors': errors})
```

contact_form.html:

```
</head>
<body>
<div>
<h1>Contact us</h1>

{% if errors %}
    <ul>
        {% for error in errors %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}

<form action="/contact/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}{% csrf_token %}
    <p>Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"></p>
    <p>Your e-mail (optional): <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <p>Message: <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50"> </textarea></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But it raise this error when I submit the form:

```
Exception Type:     ConnectionRefusedError
Exception Value:    [Errno 111] Connection refused
Exception Location: /usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py in create_connection, line 503
```

Where is the problem?
For more explanationm I use:

- Django Version:   1.8.2
- Python Version:   3.4.3

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the connection to the mail server. You should show your email settings.

Comment: Sorry I ask it but where is the email settings in the django file? I mean where is it's directory path in django?

Comment: sometimes gmail blocks connections assuming it is not the user, especially coming from cloud servers. they will send you an email about it after couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the correct connection settings in `settings.py` file for gmail:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'your gmail account'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'your gmail account password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'your gmail account'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'to email'
```

Comment: I added these:

EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myusername'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'mygmail@gmail.com'
DEFAULT_TO_EMAIL = 'to email'

but it raised this:

`Exception Type:  SMTPAuthenticationError`
`Exception Value:  (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8`

Comment: I think the error is self-explanatory - you didn't pass the authentication on SMTP server. You should set the correct Username and Password, the real one that you've registered at gmail.